# Counter in a Recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python and programming in general. I have written a function which will search adjoining elements in an array and look for ones with values within 0.05 of each other much like a floodfill algorithm does. The only difference is I am doing something stupid when it comes to counting how many time the function is run (which I am thinking will also tell me how many elements I found), so my counter values are wrong. The code works when it comes to finding adjoining elements within 0.05 of each other, just the counting is funny.

```
def floodcount (x,y,array,value,count=0):     #akin to a bucket fill in paint, finds the area instead

    nrows = len(array)-1          #rows of the image
    ncols = len(array[0])-1       #columns of the image
    diff = array[x][y] - value
    if (diff < 0.00) or (diff > 0.05): # the base case, finding a diff more than 0.05 or less than 0 is like finding a boundary
        return 0

    count = count +1
    print 'count1 ',count

    array[x][y] = -5 # so we do no calculate this pixel again
    #print "[",x,",",y,"]"
    if x > 0:
        #print '1'# if not the first elemnet then can go back, this makes sure that x is within the array all the time
        floodcount (x-1,y,array,value,count)
    if y > 0:
        #print '2'
        floodcount (x,y-1,array,value,count) 
    if x < nrows:
        #print '3'
        floodcount (x+1,y,array,value,count)
    if y < ncols:
        #print '4'
        floodcount (x,y+1,array,value,count)
    if x > 0 and y > 0:
        #print '5'
        floodcount (x-1,y-1,array,value,count)
    if x < nrows and y < ncols:
        #print '6'
        floodcount (x+1,y+1,array,value,count)
    if x <nrows and y > 0:
        #print '7'
        floodcount (x+1,y-1,array,value,count)
    if x > 0 and y < ncols:
        #print '8'
        floodcount (x-1,y+1,array,value,count)

    print 'count2 ',count    
    return count
```

So for a test case

array = [[5,1,1,3,4],[4,5,6,2,5],[5,8,5,5,9]]
x=0 and y=0

OUTPUT

count1  1
count1  2
count1  3
count1  4
count1  5
count2  5
count2  4
count2  3
count1  3
count2  3
count2  2
count2  1

As you can see something is fishy :P
Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think nrows and ncols should be renamed because they aren't actually storing the number of rows and columns (I got confused by this when trying to answer).  Remove the -1 from their initialization and change your if statement logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the now solved count problem:

You can reduce the number of `if` statements by doing all recursive calls everytime and just checking the array borders at the beginning of the function with `if x < 0 or y < 0 or x > nrows or y > ncols`.

```
#akin to a bucket fill in paint, finds the area instead
def floodcount (x,y,array,value,count=0): 
    nrows = len(array)-1          #rows of the image
    ncols = len(array[0])-1       #columns of the image
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x > nrows or y > ncols:
        return count

    diff = array[x][y] - value
    # the base case, finding a diff more than 0.05 or less than 0 is like finding a boundary
    if (diff < 0.00) or (diff > 0.05): 
        return count

    count = count +1
    print 'count1 ',count

    array[x][y] = -5 # so we do no calculate this pixel again
    #print "[",x,",",y,"]"

    count = floodcount (x-1,y,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x,y+1,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x+1,y,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x,y-1,array,value,count)

    count = floodcount (x-1,y-1,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x+1,y+1,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x+1,y-1,array,value,count)
    count = floodcount (x-1,y+1,array,value,count)

    print 'count2 ',count    
    return count
```

Answer (score 3):

So the `floodcount()` is returning the new `count` value. But you never store it / use it :)

Replace lines like:

```
floodcount(x+1, y-1, array, value, count)
```

With:

```
count = floodcount(x+1, y-1, array, value, count)
```

Comment: I think you want to change the `return 0` to `return counter`
in `if (diff < 0.00) or (diff > 0.05)` too.

Answer (score 2):

The result you obtain is expected

**UPDATE**: My explication (here under) is not exactly right. *(Thanks to Ben for the enlightenment)*. (Nevertheless, my solution proposals are correct)

> The count argument is passed **by value** to the recursive call and
>   **not by reference**. This means that the incrementations you make in subcalls has no effect on your count variable in the current function
>   (=local function variable).

You can achieve the wanted result by either using global variables:

```
count = 0
def floodcount (x,y,array,value):
    global count
    ...
```

Or by having a counter in a wrapping class (objects are passed by reference):

```
class CounterClass:
    cnt = 0

def floodcount (x,y,array,value, counter):
    ...
    counter.cnt += 1
    ...
```

Or else: Return the counter produced by your function:

```
count = floodcount(x+1, y-1, array, value, count)
```

Comment: This is not strictly speaking true. In Python everything is passed by reference. It's just that `count += 1` doesn't modify the object referred to by `count` (when `count` is an integer), it instead creates a new integer and then binds `count` to that. So, as with all name bindings, it only has an effect in the local scope and not on any other references to the same thing `count` referred to. This is because there is **nothing** you can do to modify an integer, you can only create new integer objects from operations on old ones.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the enlightment

Comment: +1 for pointing to the reference/value (mutable/immutable) things, as i thing this might be the issue the OP doesn't understand

Answer (score 1):

You call `floodcount` recursively, feeding it the current `count` to start from, and it dutifully returns the `count` it had when it was done. Which you then ignore, and go on to the next recursive call with the same `count` you passed into the first recursive call. Try changing all the recursive calls to `count = floodcount(...)`.

Comment: I tried that, but it gave the output 
count1  1
count1  1
count1  1
count1  1
count1  1
count2  0
count2  0
count2  0
count1  1
count2  0
count2  0
count2  0

but declaring count as global worked fine (just as gecco suggested). However, from your earlier comment on Gecco's post it seems that it wasnt meant to work? Any suggestions or should i just stick to what works?

Comment: @Elegant_Cow: Well the global variable will fail if you need to call this function more than once and you forget to reset it to 0. Are you sure you were still passing count **in** when you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Works now, thank you very much. Now I know of the pitfalls with global variables :)

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are both greater then 0 you will run `floodcount()` twice. Is that what you want? Seems like you would only want to run floodcount once per element in the array. If that is the case, modify your code to use `if/elif` instead of just `if`

```
if x > 0:
    floodcount (x-1,y,array,value,count)
elif y > 0:
    floodcount (x,y-1,array,value,count) 

#elif all the rest
```